# Get Access to XMLNode

Tags: c#, xml, xmlnodelist

i want to read some values of an XML File. I'm able to read some values, but I want to get the Information between the `<tools></tools>`-tags.

```
XmlNodeList xnList = xml.SelectNodes("/instructions/Steps");
foreach (XmlNode xn in xnList)
{

    XmlNodeList xnChildList = xn.ChildNodes;
    foreach (XmlNode xnc in xnChildList)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("ID: " + xnc["ID"].InnerText + "Desc: " + xnc["desc"].InnerText);
        //this one is working so far!


        //I tried to create a new XMLNodeList

        XmlNodeList testNodeList = xnc.SelectNodes("/tools");
        foreach (XmlNode node in testNodeList)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(node["tool"].InnerXml);
        }
    }
}
```

But it's not working. How can I address the tools-section?

XML file looks like this:

```
<instructions>
    <Steps QualificationID="12,3">
                <Step>
                    <ID>1.1</ID>
                    <desc>desc</desc>
                    <tools>
                        <tool ID = "1" name = "10Zoll Steckschl" />
                        <tool ID = "2" name = "5Zoll Steckschl" />
                    </tools>
                </Step>
                <Step>
                    <ID>1.2</ID>
                    <desc>desc2</desc>
                    <tools>
                        <tool ID = "3" name = "11Zoll Steckschl" />
                        <tool ID = "4" name = "54Zoll Steckschl" />
                    </tools>
                </Step>
    </Steps>
    <Steps QualificationID="1223,3">
                <Step>
                    <ID>2.1</ID>
                    <desc>desc3</desc>
                    <tools>
                        <tool ID = "5" name = "14Zoll Steckschl" />
                        <tool ID = "6" name = "2Zoll Steckschl" />
                    </tools>
                </Step>
                <Step>
                    <ID>2.2</ID>
                    <desc>desc4</desc>
                    <tools>
                        <tool ID = "7" name = "13Zoll Steckschl" />
                        <tool ID = "8" name = "4Zoll Steckschl" />
                    </tools>
                </Step>
    </Steps>
</instructions>
```

Comment: "it's not working" isn't a precise description of the problem. What's happening, compared with what you expected to happen? (And do you have to use XmlDocument and XPath? I'd personally use LINQ to XML instead...)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I strongly *suspect* this is the problem:

```
XmlNodeList testNodeList = xnc.SelectNodes("/tools");
```

The leading slash is taking it back up to the root node - you only want to look for `tools` elements *under* `xnc`:

```
XmlNodeList testNodeList = xnc.SelectNodes("tools");
```

This sort of thing is why I'd personally prefer to use LINQ to XML :)

```
XDocument doc = ...;
foreach (var step in doc.Root.Elements("Steps").Elements("Step"))
{
     MessageBox.Show(string.Format("ID: {0} Desc: {1}",
                     step.Element("ID").Value, step.Element("desc").Value);

     foreach (var tool in step.Elements("tools"))
     {
         ...
     }
}
```